# Substring in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix

Suppose I have a string "123456789".

I want to extract the 3rd, 6th, and 8th element. I guess I can use

```
cut -3, -6, -8
```

But if this gives

```
368
```

Suppose I want to separate them by a white space to get

```
3 6 8
```

What should I do?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma He tried `cut`.

Comment: Which shell are you using? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @SmithBlack `cut` can provide the desired output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) tool and issue this command in your teminal:

```
sed -r "s/^..(.)..(.).(.).*$/\1 \2 \3/"
```

Explained RegEx: http://regex101.com/r/fH7zW6

---

To "generalize" this on a file you can pipe it after a `cat` like so:

```
cat file.txt|sed -r "s/^..(.)..(.).(.).*$/\1 \2 \3/"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems like this part "..(.)..(.).(.)."   works when we know the length of the string. If we don't know how many characters in each line (possible very big number), does this still work?

Comment: This works when the line has at least 8 characters as it discards anything else after the 8th so yes, it can very big.

Comment: No need for a cat. Just redirect the file to sed. `sed … < file`

Comment: Thank you. Just a follow up question. If I want to extract the 999th character, do I need to put 998 "." followed by "(.)" ?

Comment: no, put `.{998}(.)` I used multiple dots (without quantifier) to be simpler, it's equivalent to: `/^.{2}(.).{2}(.).(.).*$/`

Answer (score 2):

Actually shell parameter expansion lets you do substring slicing directly, so you could just do:

```
x='123456789'
echo "${x:3:1}" "${x:6:1}" "${x:8:1}"
```

#### Update

To do this over an entire file, read the line in a loop:

```
while read x; do
  echo "${x:3:1}" "${x:6:1}" "${x:8:1}"
done < file
```

(By the way, bash slicing is zero-indexed, so if you want the numbers '3', '6' and '8' you'd really want `${x:2:1} ${x:5:1} and {$x:7:1}`.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to generalize this to extracting the 3rd, 6th, and 8th characters for all lines in a file?

Comment: Can you try `echo "${x:2:1}" "${x:5:1}" "${x:7:1}"` instead?  In both bashes (Linux and OSX) I've tested, the character counting is 0-based, not 1-based

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner.

```
perl -lne '@A = split //; print "$A[2] $A[5] $A[7]"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
$ cat input
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
5678901234
$ cut -b3,6,8 --output-delimiter=" " input
3 6 8
4 7 9
5 8 0
6 9 1
7 0 2
```

The `-b` option selects only the specified bytes.  The output delimiter can be specified using `--output-delimiter`.